# EclipseLink TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, transactions, eclipselink, jta

i have problem with transactions in my project.
When i call method which used sql query to  deletes rows from database i get error:

`Warning:   /class/HistoryList.xhtml @28,245 actionListener="#{planConfirmedController.delete(planController.historyDate,planController.selectedDate)}": javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: executeUpdate is not supported for a Query object obtained through non-transactional access of a container-managed transactional EntityManager
javax.el.ELException: /class/HistoryList.xhtml @28,245 actionListener="#{planConfirmedController.delete(planController.historyDate,planController.selectedDate)}": javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: executeUpdate is not supported for a Query object obtained through non-transactional access of a container-managed transactional EntityManager
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
......................`

here is the query:

`"DELETE c FROM Class c WHERE c.classname = :classname"`

delete method (wrote from memory because i don't have access to original code now)

```
@Transactional
public void delete(Date d1, Date d2)
{

...
Query q = ejbFacade.createNamedQuery("..") ;
q.executeUpdate() ;

}
...
```

I using executeUpdate method to execute query

My glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<parametr-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_pup_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" ping="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" pooling="true" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-cache-size="0" statement-leak-reclaim="false" statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">        <property name="serverName" value="...."/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="pup"/>
    <property name="User" value="username"/>
    <property name="Password" value="password"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://....:3306/pup?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="pup" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_pup_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

and persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="pupPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>pup</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Application using eclipselink to communicate with database. Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the code calling the @Transactional annotated method.

Make sure that when calling the method you are using the method stub created by the framework and not the method directly.

In other words, assuming this method is written in some EJB, you should be calling the method from an EJB client using the injected EJB instance as opposed to calling the method from within the EJB instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to paste code from my xhtml page
I calling method delete in this way:

```
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"  value="#{bundle.Delete}" actionListener="#{planConfirmedController.delete(planController.historyDate,planController.selectedDate)}" update=":growl,:ClassListForm">
     <p:confirm header="Usunięcie" message="Czy napewno chcesz usunąć wpis z historii dla aktualnie wybranych danych?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

part of planConfirmedController source code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "planConfirmedController")
@SessionScoped
public class PlanConfirmedController implements Serializable {
@EJB
private pup_dao.PlanConfirmedFacade planConfirmedFacade ;
```

The planConfirmedFacde in my first post in delete method is called ejbFacade (by mistake)

**ok I finally solve this problem. Transactions didn't work because in controller i used @ManagedBean instead of @Named annotation.**